# How do I use imagemagick with Python?

Tags: python, ubuntu, imagemagick, python-tesseract, wand

I have following two commands that I want to implement using Python. I am completely newbie to Imagemagick so can anyone tell me how can I use the below commands in Python? I guess I am gonna have to use Wand?

```
convert input.png -crop 762x41+32+100 -units pixelsperinch -density 300 image.png

convert image.png -auto-level -negate -threshold 70% crop_processed.png

tesseract crop-processed.png stdout
```

Input image:

[image]

Comment: -units and -density will have no effect on the raster png image output. They only are useful when printing. But if you the threshold the image, it likely will not help. So all you need to do is `convert input.png -crop 755x37+34+99 -auto-level -negate -threshold 70% crop_processed.png` Please post your input image, so we can process with it.

Comment: I have edited my original post and added the input image and updated the dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is how to do that in Python Wand.**

Input:

[image]

```
from wand.image import Image
from wand.display import display

with Image(filename='stockholm.jpg') as img:
    img.crop(left=34, top=99, width=755, height=37)
    img.auto_level()
    img.negate()
    img.threshold(threshold=0.70)
    img.save(filename='stockhold_processed.png')
    display(img)
```

Result:

[image]

**Or using Python/OpenCV**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('stockholm.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# crop image
img = img[99:99+37, 34:34+755]

# threshold image
img_thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# view result
cv2.imshow("threshold", img_thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save result
cv2.imwrite("stockholm_crop_threshold.png", img_thresh)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I used your original dimensions. But you can change the code now that you see how.

Comment: Awesome! How can I pass the result to tesseract in python?

Comment: Sorry, I have not used tesseract.